# App linking not working. How to open app from web browser?

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-linking

I've followed the steps in the android documentation [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html#adding-filters) to implement linking in my application. I dont really need any fancy parameter passing, all I want is when the user clicks a link on the browser that my app opens. All I did was modify my AndroidManifest. Here is the relevant part

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="u2player" android:host="open.my.app" />
    </intent-filter>


  </activity>
```

I am using react-native-navigation and trying to browse from either the chrome browser or the native browser to any of `u2player://` `u2player://open.my.app` `u2player://open.my.app/` doesn't work. I have also binded the `url` event from the Linking module but nothing works. I restarted, uninstalled, etc.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try using [branch](https://branch.io/). It solves most of the problem that you are facing and it also has a very clean documentation. Please go through and let me know if you have any issues